# Can a relative clause be a compound sentence?

Tags: grammar, syntactic-analysis, relative-clauses

*They began to believe **that** their way of doing business was failing and **that** their incomes would therefore shortly begin to fall as well.*

In this sentence, can I remove the second "that" while keeping the sentence gramatically correct, so that the relative clause becomes a compound sentence?

I read this sentence as an exercise of proofreading and did not find the source.

Comment: You could, but I wouldn't recommend it. The two _thats_ are sufficiently far apart not to be too repetitive. Incidentally. they are declarative content clauses, not relative ones.

Comment: Relatively speaking, 'This is the house that Jack built and that the big bad wolf couldn't blow down' sounds better than 'This is the house that Jack built, and the big bad wolf couldn't blow down'.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Yes, deletions of complementizers are often ill-advised. And those are **not** relative clauses, which should be emphasized. They're complement clauses and _that_ is just a complementizer, not a relative pronoun.

Comment: Thank you so much guys.